# How can I get all element's immediate children with css selectors using selenium?

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I already tried using the ">" syntax but selenium does not accept it, I know there is a way to get it using Xpath but our entire project is written using CSS selectors.

I am trying to store a list that will contain all immediate children of an element but not their children (descendants), when I use the "*" syntax I get all the element's descendants.

Comment: Do you mean that `body > *` does not give you all direct descendants of the body tag in Selenium?

Comment: Can you give an example of the CSS selector you are using.  In Selenium RC we've got most of our code using CSS selectors with no issue so I'd be surprised if in Selenium2 they've taken a step backwards.

Comment: @jro , I've tried using 
'someWebElement.findElement(By.cssSelector(">*"))'
The exception thrown is: 
"invalidElementStateException".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should specify a tag to start from... if you want *"all element's immediate children"*, you would simply get all elements, which isn't really what you want.

To get *"all immediate children of an element but not their children"* for `body`, use `body > *`.

Or another example, to get all direct descendants of `<div id='question'>`, use `div#question > *`.

Comment: Thanks! that was helpful!!! We tried to use the > * in relativity to the webElement (like: `someWebElement.findElements(By.cssSelector(">*"))), instead of: webDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector(elementLocator + ">*").`

Comment: Be aware that this is an extremely inefficient selector! Css selectors are validated from right to left so by using the asterix (*, aka universal selector) at the end of the selector the browser will select all elements and then starts filtering further (in this case: only the elements that are direct children of the 'body' element).
So for small pages this would not be an issue but in larger single page apps it can slow things down...